# Debugging with disassembly in visual studio 2015

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, x86, disassembly

Every time i debug a code in vs 2015 and view the assembly code, I notice that the "step into" and "step over" buttons goes to the next C code instruction without stopping at the assembly code between the instructions.
For example:

```
int foo()
{
  push   ebp
  mov    ebp,esp
return 0x1111
  mov    eax,01111h
}
```

When I enter foo() it stops at the 'push ebp' instruction but when I click the step into instruction it won't go to the 'move ebp,esp' instruction but it will go to the return line.
How do I make it go to the next assembly instruction rather than the next code instruction.
Thanks.

Comment: which window is active when you press F11 ? must be disassembly window active for step asm instruction one by one

Comment: Ah it works! Thanks!